# Same function shows different values at different places

Tags: javascript

I am making a coin toss application here, everything works well except this part where the `coinTossResult()` shows tails in `resultText.innerHTML`, whereas when I log it on to the console in the next line it shows head. Otherwise when `coinTossResult()` shows tails in `resultText.innerHTML` it matches with the console.log. No idea why its happening.

```
resultText.innerHTML = `The Computer chose ${compChoice} and it is a ${(coinTossResult())}`
console.log(compChoice, coinTossResult());
```

Here is my full code:

```
    const btnChoices = document.querySelectorAll('.options');
    const resultText = document.querySelector('.result-text');
    const tossWinText = document.querySelector('.toss-winner');
    const turnText = document.querySelector('.turn-text');
    const btnArea = document.querySelector('.buttons');
    let playerChoice =[];
    let compChoice = [];


    function whoseTurn(){
    if(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) === 0){
        turnText.innerHTML = 'Computer will flip the coin';
        btnArea.style.display = "none";
        const options = ['head', 'tails'];
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length);
        compChoice = options[random];
        resultText.innerHTML = `The Computer chose ${compChoice} and it is a ${(coinTossResult())}`
        console.log(compChoice, coinTossResult());
    }else{
        turnText.innerHTML = 'Player will flip the coin';
        btnChoices.forEach(function(e){
            e.addEventListener('click', function(){
                if(e.classList.contains('head')){
                   playerChoice = 'head';
                }else{
                    playerChoice = 'tails';
                }
                resultText.innerHTML = `The Player chose ${playerChoice} and it is a ${coinTossResult()}`
                if(playerChoice === coinTossResult()){
                    tossWinText.innerHTML = 'Player has won the Toss';
                }else{
                    tossWinText.innerHTML = 'Computer has won the Toss';
                }
            })
            
        })
        
        
    }
}
function coinTossResult(){
    const opt = ['head', 'tails'];
    const ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * opt.length);
    const cho = opt[ran];
    return cho;
}
whoseTurn();
```

Comment: The function is for coin toss result, the other one is for computers choice, which is also random

Comment: OK, so the problem is simply that you're calling `coinTossResult()` twice, once when creating the innerHTML and then again in the console.log. Obviously, each time you call it, it will return a random boolean value.

Comment: only when the console shows head it shows tails in the innerhtml, otherwise it shows the same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the method twice

```
coinTossResult()
```

assign it to a variable and console.log it